# Criando tabelas automáticas pelo Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Boa tarde,

estou tentando criar as tabelas de forma automática, sendo que eu acho que deve está faltando alguma coisa.

alguém pode me ajuda?

essa é minha linha de código

**Cargo.java**

```
package br.com.teste;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table
public class Cargo implements Serializable {

    private int id;

    private String descricao;

    public String getDescricao() {    
        return descricao;    
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {    
        this.descricao = descricao;    
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {    
        return id;    
    }

    public void setId(int id) {    
        this.id = id;    
    }    
}
```

**Funcionario.java**

```
package br.com.teste;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Funcionario {

    private int id;

    private String nome;

    private String email;

    private Cargo cargo = new Cargo();

    public Cargo getCargo() {    
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(Cargo cargo) {    
        this.cargo = cargo;    
    }

    public String getEmail() {    
        return email;    
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {    
        this.email = email;    
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {    
        return id;    
    }

    public void setId(int id) {    
        this.id = id;    
    }

    public String getNome() {    
        return nome;    
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {    
        this.nome = nome;    
    }    
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql:/localhost/teste</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect </property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="br.com.teste.Cargo"/>

        <mapping class="br.com.teste.Funcionario"/>

        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**console (logs)**

```
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Projeto' did not find a matching property.
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 587 ms
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFORMAÇÕES: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.7 (SNAPSHOT 20120206) para o contexto '/Projeto'
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Ago 11, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
```

Comment: A URL do seu banco deve conter a porta:
jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/teste

Comment: realmente tinha esquecido sendo que ainda não resolveu.

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro no log?

Comment: Ressuscitando essa questão, tem como você disponibilizar o `persistence.xml`, wladyband? Ou a duvida já foi esclarecida?

Answer (score 1):

Suas tabelas ainda não foram criadas e/ou você ainda não obteve nenhum erro/sucesso porquê o Hibernate ainda não foi acionado de alguma maneira pela sua aplicação (estou supondo que você está em um container web em vez de um servidor de aplicação).

Caso opte por usar as classes da especificação da JPA (persistence.xml) ao invés do Hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml), você pode fazer:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nomeDaSuaEntityManager"); // no caso do xml, o nome da entityManager é "local".
```

Para evitar qualquer surpresa, estou colocando um exemplo de persistence.xml que funciona em um tomcat:

```
<persistence
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="local" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```